# Confining a Linux user to a single application

Tags: linux, security

I would like to confine a Linux user to a single application, or browser activity. I have sensitive data on the system hence the user (client) should not be able to do anything else (no terminal/editors, etc). How could I approach towards this goal?

Comment: I think you can try use selinux in kiosk mode if you are using Redhat based distro, please tell what distro you are using when you do a question.

Comment: I have not made the choice yet, as I am looking for the best option. IIRC I see that selinux has xguest mode that allows only firefox and optionally allows execute permission on home and /tmp directories. Does this mean terminal, shell and editors are/ can be disabled?

Comment: yes, that xguest is selinux in kiosk mode, anyway if you use a Linux user with xguest selinux profile, that user can't do anything unless you give the permissions to do it, read the redhat docs about this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have sensitive files, start with securing the files.  This should be done even if you don't intend to let other users to access the system.

Linux/Unix has a strong permissions system.  Ensure none of the sensitive files are readable by `others`.  This can be done by restricting access to any directory along the path.

It is not uncommon to set the permissions on home directories to `700` which allows only the user and root to see the contents.  Set your restricted user up with their own group, which on some distributions is the default.

Audit you system to see what files can be accessed with `others` permissions.

If some of the sensitive data is in a database, audit its permissions.

If you allow the user access to a browser, they will normally be able to browse the file system.  Besides kiosk mode, you may want to consider using a `chroot` to restrict them to a small portion of the system.  This can be difficult to setup for an X-window environment as it needs a fair number of files and devices.  I would expect an `xguest` profile would need to allow access to the same files and directories as chrooted environment.  You can combine approaches it implement Defense in Depth.

It is relatively, easy to attempt to restrict an X-window user to a single application.  Just start that application instead of starting a Window Manager.  As long as that application can not start other applications you have restricted them to that application.  Explore the capabilities of that application as it may be able to browse and possibly execute files.   Does it have a `kiosk` mode intended to restrict access.

If there are flaws in the configuration, the user may be able to escape their jail.  I have used a few tricks to gain access to `explorer` and other tools on a supposedly locked-down Windows system.  This is where correct file and directory permissions come in to full force.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Keep sensitive data on external drive.**

My experience tells, that firefox can spawn ssh process and try to connect with malicious ip's. For a year of using firefox i have like ~200 tries. So if possible keep sensitive data on external drive or spawn firefox as another user.

**2. Add second user.**

OP question isn't strait forward, because we don't know if he will be also using this PC. So create another user and install Windows Manager something like fluxbox should be enough.

**3. Execute '[startx browser](https://superuser.com/questions/219511/browser-instead-of-window-manager)' only, for second user.**

So for second user you could edit (in my case im using lxqt): `./etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.lxqt` or `./usr/bin/startlxqt` and add there your browser.

**4. If you want just kiosk OS try [porteus](http://porteus-kiosk.org/index.html)**

What's the problem, if you want me to extend my answer just ask.